# Initialization issue in java.util.Map to LinkedHashMap?

Tags: android, dictionary, linkedhashmap

I had found a weird problem in Android code, that my buddy developer is working with. When we tried to initialize a Map object as a LinkedHashMap, it showed some kinda error. Our first attempt was

**Map postRequestMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();**

I thought maybe it's due to some JDK version issue and changed to

**Map postRequestMap = new LinkedHashMap();**

but both the attempts was futile. So I was forced to changed it to 
**LinkedHashMap postRequestMap = new LinkedHashMap();**
 I checked the same in my machine, having JDK 1.8 update 20, and the code was just working fine. Could anybody help me to figure out this issue,  please ?

Comment: I guess `java.util.Map` wasn't imported, or `LinkedHashMap` was somekind of exotic version, not `java.util.LinkedHashMap`.